# Why is the formula repeated in the loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am currently self-studying LPU's Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python. However, I am having trouble with the loop part. Like in this case, why is there a need to repeat the formula ans = (high+low)/2 again in the while loop?

```
x = 20
epsilon = 0.02
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans)
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low)/2.0
print('numGuesses =', numGuesses)
print(ans, 'is close to square root of', x)
```

Comment: Because its value changes !

Comment: if you wrote this code, shouldn't you know why its needed? what are you trying to achieve? what happens if you remove it (endless loop)?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you invest some time learning how to debug a Python program

Answer (score 0):

Because, in the sixth line, you set the initial value for *ans* to 10 and after you enter in the *while* loop, the *ans* value continually  change until the value is approximated to the square root of 20. Below, the output of the code, obtained by the *print* function.

```
low = 0.0 high = 20 ans = 10.0
low = 0.0 high = 10.0 ans = 5.0
low = 0.0 high = 5.0 ans = 2.5
low = 2.5 high = 5.0 ans = 3.75
low = 3.75 high = 5.0 ans = 4.375
low = 4.375 high = 5.0 ans = 4.6875
low = 4.375 high = 4.6875 ans = 4.53125
low = 4.375 high = 4.53125 ans = 4.453125
low = 4.453125 high = 4.53125 ans = 4.4921875
```

If you observe the output of your own code, you can see that the *ans* value is recalculated because the *high* and *low* values are dinamically changing based on the conditional interaction of the *ans* value and the *x* value.

Just to clarify more, try to comment the line of the second setting for *ans* and observe the results!